# Excel to DataTable Error in c#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I have a strange problem,
when i try to open and load excel data to a DataTable,
some data in excel sheet loads but some data doesn't load,
what is the problem,
can you help me.
I added GetExcelData function,
please look at this code,
and please tell me what is the problem.

```
GROUP      CLASS       TYPE      C1       C2       C3       C4      C4       C5
M1         10          A         D        B        D        A       A        D
M1         10          B         C        D        E        E       D        D
M2         11          A         D        D        D        D       D        E
M2         11          B         C        D        E        D       E        A
```

Above i placed the sample sheet.
it copies only datas that are in GROUP, CLASS AND TYPE columns.
But strange is that in some excel files this error doesn't occur,
and i didn't find the answer, decided to ask it here.

```
public DataTable GetExcelData(string fileName, string sheetName)
    {
        string sql = "";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand command;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        command = conn.CreateCommand();
        string excel_file = fileName;
        string excel_type = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(excel_file);
        string connstr = ""; 

        if(excel_type=="XLSX")
            connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
        else
            connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1; HDR=YES'";

        conn.ConnectionString = connstr;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "$]";

        command.CommandText = sql;
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: please add more info on what data loads and what does not, we also need to know the contents of the excel sheet, at least the data types

Comment: Wouldn't you need to swap the two connection strings? You're using Excel 8.0 for .xlsx files which (I believe) should be the ther way around.

Comment: @xxbbcc: I thought the same thing at first but the code will work because the call to `GetExtension()` will return ".xlsx" and not "XLSX", which means that the correct connection string will be inadvertently chosen. So it works but for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 0):

since your first connection string

```
connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
```

is not having IMEX=1 it will not be able to import mixed types columns,It is happening only sometimes because of your if clause.Same with HDR, in 1 case HDR is missing. your connection string in if condition should be,

```
connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```